# Coq: defining a function from a sigma type to its second projection (and making it a coercion)

Tags: types, coq, proof, coercion, subtype

I have trouble proving the type of the second projection from a sigma type:

```
Variable X:Type.
Variable Phy: X -> Type.
Definition e {x:X}: {x:X & Phy x} -> Phy x. 
intro. Fail exact (@projT2 _ _ X0).
(*The term "projT2 X0" has type "Phy (projT1 X0)"
while it is expected to have type "Phy x" (cannot unify
"(fun x : X => Phy x) (projT1 X0)" and "Phy x").*)
```

Is it the case that having a witness of `{x:X & Phy x}` (or `{x:X | Phy x}`) is insufficient for obtaining a witness of `Phy x` via projections? Either way, I could define `e` (more stupidly) by assuming the witnesses. Furthermore, I want to make it a coercion (but fail):

```
Reset e.
Definition PhyX := {x:X & Phy x}.
Definition e {x:X} {z:Phy x} {y:PhyX}: PhyX -> Phy x := fun y => z.
Coercion e: PhyX >-> Funclass. (*e does not respect the uniform inheritance condition*)
```

Now to the question: **Can I define `e` more sensibly and/or make it a coercion?**

EDIT: I suppose assuming a witness of `Phy x` is necessary because of the way `existT` is [declared](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual005.html#hevea_default222): `existT (x:A) (_:P x)`. Here's a better version of the 2 last lines of code above (still couldn't make it a coercion):

```
Definition e {x:X} {h:Phy x}: PhyX -> Phy x := fun _ => projT2 (existT _ _ h).
Coercion e: PhyX >-> Phy. (*e does not respect the uniform inheritance condition*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition, there are two `X` values: the one given as an argument with `{x:X}`, and the one hidden in the sigma. These two are not interchangeable.

What you *can* do is this:

```
Definition e (p : {x:X & Phy x}) : Phy (projT1 p).
  destruct p; simpl; assumption.
Defined.
```

Comment: Amazingly, this works for the coercion. Why? Was it that 2 non-interchangeable `X`-s broke the uniform inheritance condition (or is there a simpler explanation)?

Comment: Well, it's just a projection.  In the stdlib, this function is called `projT2`.

Comment: OK. But why `Definition e {x:X} {h:Phy x}: PhyX -> Phy x := fun _ => projT2 (existT _ _ h)` violated the UIC?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "violated the UIC"? That definition type checks.

Comment: The uniform inheritance condition. It's on [coercions](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual021.html#sec665)